Error while upgrading to azure-identity 1.16.1 from 1.10.0
We are currently using azure-identity 1.10.0 and have to upgrade to 1.16.1, after upgrading getting the following error :
DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. Attempted credentials: EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
Note: I upgraded azure storage-blob recently from 12.12.0 to 12.13.0 and the token was retrieved successfully without giving any error.
Can anyone help here?

Your error says

Environment variables are not fully configured.

You need to re-configure your environment variables.
Generally, you have to re-enter your credentials after any change you make in Azure.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#environment-variables
